# Failure for grpc server side streaming (with subsequest CORS error)

Tags: streaming, grpc, cloudflare, deadlines

I am able to implement unary calls using grpc-web but server side streaming doesn't work as expected.
When first open the page, CreateStream is called and works as expected. the network tab looks like this: (there's preflight response but not shown in the screenshot)
[image]

This is CreateStream 200 detail:
[image]

After around 1 minutes 30-40 seconds, there will be this error:
[image]

There will be another pending CreateStream when that error occured:
[image]

My envoy.yaml looks like this:

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address: 
      socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 30800 }
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          stream_idle_timeout: 0s
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match: { prefix: "/auth." }
                route: 
                  cluster: auth_service
                  max_grpc_timeout: 0s
              - match: { prefix: "/name_of_service." }
                route: 
                  cluster: stream_service
                  timeout: 0s
                  max_grpc_timeout: 0s
              cors:
                allow_origin_string_match:
                - prefix: "*"
                allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                allow_headers: access-control-allow-origin,keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,access-token,token, authorize-token,x-site-type,x-origin,x-pin-token,grpc-timeout
                expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_web
          - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
```

This error always occur every 1 minute 30/40 seconds. That means the red error messages in the console will be a lot if I don't close the page.
I have also tried setting deadline on customer side but its no use. How to fix this CORS error? I haven't look at the cloudflare because idk what to look at, and also if cloudflare is the problem why do unary calls and the first server streaming call works?
Thanks

Comment: The root problem is not a CORS error but instead some other problem — some failure which prevents the server from sending/completing the response the browser expects. When you check the server logs of the server that response is coming from, what relevant messages do you find have been logged there?

Comment: @sideshowbarker I check my grpc service and envoy logs, no error... The grpc service can also be run locally and theres no error in bloomrpc